# tables not working properly on JODReports

Tags: freemarker

I'm working with JODReports to generate some documents from a model on grails. Everything works fine but table directives. I need to make a table with a set of messages but my template only repeats the @table:table-row text instead of actually inserting a row.
my code looks like this:

```
@table:table-row
[#list msg as row]

@/table:table-row
[/#list]
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you put this code inside a table cell, as described [here](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/?q=node/26) ? Paste some of your code, i.e. how do you invoke jodreports.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a lot of things wrong. JODReports documentation is not good enough for me. I didn't know you have to put this in a table cell and I didn't know that I have to use @table:table-cell in order to fill it. Here is mi final code. I inserted it in a JOOScript script in the first table's cell and it worked perfectly

```
@table:table-row
[#list msg as celltext]
@table:table-cell
@/table:table-cell
@/table:table-row
[/#list]
```